# Should the translate tool be causing uneven faces?

Tags: modeling

[image]

When trying to make/edit models for some reason this started happening. The picture is just a square with an edge down the middle that I pulled down on one point. The two faces that were effected transformed in different ways, and it seems to consistently do this no matter the shape I'm editing.

Comment: That is clearly not just a "*square with an edge down the middle*", I see 3 quads and one triangle in there at least. Due to the nature of computer graphics computers can only really ever draw triangles in 3D space. Whichever other more complex shapes you make are always broken down into simpler primitives made of triangles. Four-sided faces                   are always composed of 2 triangles and there is really no way to control directly how it gets subdivided in Blender, so some times it may yield slightly different results.

Comment: Think of it as triangles. Blender calculates all quads as triangles. That should define your line, and with that mindset, you can figure out how to fix it.